# Javascript code breaks when data has null

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code which works great but totally stops working when "thsub" is null and does not continue reading the rest of the data and just returns a TypeError saying "thsub in null"

Here is the code:

```
var data = {
  "cars": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "name 1",
      "thsub": [{
        "id": "11",
        "name": "sub 1",
        "stats": {
          "items": 5,
        },
        "ions": null
      }, {
        "id": "22",
        "name": "sub 2",
        "stats": {
          "items": 5,
        },
        "translations": null
      }],
      "image": null
    },

    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "name 2",
      "thsub": null, //this will break the code
      "image": null
    }
  ]
}



var thCount = [];

for (var l = 0, m = data.cars.length; l < m; l++) {
  thCount[l] = 0;
  for (var i = 0, j = data.cars[l].thsub.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats) {
      thCount[l]+=data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats.items;
    }
  }
}

console.log(thCount);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: At the moment all answers are adding a 0 when it's null ... I need it to skip null records. For example if it finds "thsub": null ... then skip to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is checking the length attribute of thsub. If thsub is null, then your code is attempting to check an attribute (length) of a null object, which will always break your code.. Try adding a check for the thsub object itself before checking the length:

```
for (var l = 0, m = data.cars.length; l < m; l++) {
  thCount[l] = 0;
  if (data.cars[l].thsub) {
    for (var i = 0, j = data.cars[l].thsub.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats) {
        thCount[l]+=data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats.items;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/bwmwntay/5/

Comment: instead of adding a 0 to the array, can't it just ignore it if it's null?

Answer (score 4):

It breaks because you're referencing `thsub`'s `length` property. As `null` has no properties, and cannot, this will throw an error. This can, in this situation and every other situation where you're using null, easily be worked around by adding some sort of conditional that will either break your loop or avoid executing the code.

Here's a simple example:

```
for (var l = 0, m = data.cars.length; l < m; l++) {
  if (data.cars[l].thsub) {
    for (var i = 0, j = data.cars[l].thsub.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats) {
        thCount[l]+=data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats.items;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the added `data.cars[l].thsub` -- if this value is null, the condition will evaluate to false, and the exception-causing code will never execute.

Comment: Make sure to check `data.cars[l].thsub` BEFORE checking `data.cars[l].thsub.length`

Comment: @MattSpinks Thanks, meant to do that, not sure how I missed it.

Comment: instead of adding a 0 to the array, can't it just ignore it if it's null?

Comment: @PaulTenna2000 That was there purely from your code -- if you've got no use for it, feel free to ignore it. I'll edit it out now.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @PaulTenna2000 Sure! Make sure that you select one of the answers on the page as correct once you're comfortable that your answer is solved. Have a great day!

Comment: This one is just returning NaN

Answer (score 1):

Just add a guard condition before you access a property as, an error will be thrown if you try to invoke properties on `null` or `undefined` objects.

```
for (var l = 0, m = data.cars.length; l < m; l++) {
  thCount[l] = 0;
  let tsubs = data.cars[l].thsub || []; <--- Guard condition
  for (var i = 0, j = tsubs.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats) {
      thCount[l] += data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats.items;
    }
  }
}
```

In the fixed use case `tsubs` will be set to an empty array when ever the property access returns a falsy value.

Comment: instead of adding a 0 to the array, can't it just ignore it if it's null?

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `thsub` variable first:

```
var thsub;

for (var l = 0, m = data.cars.length; l < m; l++) {
  thCount[l] = 0;
  thsub = data.cars[l].thsub;

  if (!(thsub instanceof Array)) continue; // If it's not an array, skip it.

  for (var i = 0, j = thsub.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (!thsub[i].stats) continue; // If it doesn't contain 'stats', skip it.

    thCount[l] += thsub[i].stats.items;
  }
}
```